# Fix the size of EditBOX as per background image android

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have an editBox as defined below

```
                               <EditText
                                    android:layout_below="@+id/signIn"
                                    android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
                                    android:inputType="text"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:id="@+id/username"
                                    android:textColor="@color/regular"
                                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                                    android:gravity="center"
                                    android:background="@drawable/input_filed"
                                    android:text="@string/hintUsername"
                                    android:padding="2dp"
                                    android:hint="@string/hintUsername"/>
```

I have added a background image to it, Its a custom EditBox. Now the problem is, when i type text in it, since I have used `wrap_content` so that it will stretch to its picture dimension. But this is causing the image to get stretch when more and more words are input. How can I fix the size of Editbox as per the background image , just like ImageView `adjustViewBounds`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use andriod:maxWidth to limit the width of the EditText or use 9-patch to stretch the background

Comment: maxWidth to what.. that;s the real problem :) The image background can be of any size, Lets say xhdpi, mdpi,ldpi,xxhdpi so many sizes.I Can't hardcode

Comment: may be setting in the code after the EditText is created: editText.setMaxWidth(editText.getWidth()) ?

Comment: Glad it was helpful Muhammad!